# Blank page after submission on PHP Sign up form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have been close to finding my error but I can't... please help me with the problem I have with my PHP signup form -

I have signup page, index page, login page and logout page and I set redirect statement as below;

```
$error = array();
$error[] = "each time false is returned print some message here";

        if (count($error) === 0)
    {
      header('location: ./login.php');
```

(I wish I could paste the whole page code and I don't even know where the problem really is...)

When I click submit button on signup form, it goes to a blank page and when there is an error it shows on the blank screen but when the signup is successful it doesn't show anything and stay on the blank page.

My HTML is like this

```
<h3>Please enter username and password to sign up</h3>
<form action="./signup.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Sign up">
</form>
```

Can you tell what could be the problem?
Thanks so much for the help in advance...

Comment: Check for errors in your php code with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` put this line after opening the php code.

Comment: can you post signup.php?

Comment: the code u posted does not help at all

Comment: You problably have a whitespace, or anything else, before your php tag `<?php`. If you have anything before the php tag, the header will already have been sent, when you set the header location. The header location is therefore ignored. Fix your php tag or use ob_start -
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php